# Distribution of an estimated parameter

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

I'm studying by myself, and the text says « If $\epsilon_\alpha$ is the upper $\alpha$-quantile of the distribution of $\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}$, then $P(\hat{\theta}-\epsilon_\beta\hat{\sigma}\leq \theta \leq \hat{\theta}-\epsilon_{1-\alpha}\hat{\sigma} )\geq 1-\beta-\alpha$ .»
However, from wiki, I think we have this $P(\hat{\theta}-\epsilon_\beta\hat{\sigma}\leq \theta)=P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}\leq \epsilon_\beta)\geq \beta$, together with $P(\hat{\theta}-\epsilon_{1-\alpha}\hat{\sigma}\geq \theta)=P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}\geq \epsilon_{1-\alpha})=1-P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}< \epsilon_{1-\alpha})\geq 1-(1-\alpha)=\alpha$, imply that $P(\hat{\theta}-\epsilon_\beta\hat{\sigma}\leq \theta \leq \hat{\theta}-\epsilon_{1-\alpha}\hat{\sigma} )\geq \beta-\alpha$.

So where did I go wrong?

I'm reading Asymptotics Statistics, by Van der Vaart, on page 326

Comment: Draw a picture.  (And note that when you multiply two sides of an equality by a negative value, the direction of the inequality changes.)

Comment: @whuber, are you saying it only works when $\hat{\sigma}$ is negative?

Comment: I will ignore that comment, assuming it is meant in jest.

Comment: I didn't mean it as a jest. Then could you be more helpful please? Because I didn't understand the point of your comment. Sorry.

Comment: The main point is to draw a picture of the PDF in which the relevant probabilities are shown as areas. That tends to be a clearer and less error-prone way of working with interval probabilities than algebraic manipulations in which a single error with a minus sign inside a long expression can ruin everything.  (I'm not even saying you are wrong; the issue is to determine which result is correct.)

Comment: @whuber 
Thanks. I've tried doing the graph, but I still cannot reach the same conclusion as the book...Could you help me? (P.S.: I edited the question, there was an error there.)

Comment: (1) Don't beg for help from people in comments. If whuber has useful help to offer and the time to do it in, you'll have it. If he doesn't, you're just harassing him. Better to use your time to make your question as clear and well laid-out as you can. (2) Can you describe the situation? I feel like I lack some context.

Comment: If I have correctly understood what's going on, you have a problem here: $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}\leq \epsilon_\beta)\geq \beta$

Comment: @Glen_b from what I could gather, for quantiles, $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}\leq \epsilon_\beta)\geq \beta$ and $P(\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\hat{\sigma}}< \epsilon_\beta)\leq \beta$.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes here. If I understand right, I have problems with both of those.

Comment: I took it from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Quantiles_of_a_population